# count duplicate class ids plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query an address table to check if an Id is duplicated for each owner.

My basic query show's me the address mediums and owners related to the medium.

```
owner_obj_id   addr_medium_id  is_std_addr
12345          5001            +
12345          5002            +
12345          5001            null
12346          5001            null
```

I want to query for each distinct owner_obj_id and check if they have a duplicated medium id, they shouldn't have 5001 twice for example.

Answer (score 1):

To get the duplicate combination, you can do

```
select owner_obj_id, addr_medium_id
from tablename
group by owner_obj_id, addr_medium_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Edit:

```
select owner_obj_id, addr_medium_id
from tablename
where is_std_addr is not null
group by owner_obj_id, addr_medium_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: How could i modify the query to check a flag set for each address, along with the medium_id there is flag "is_std_addr". I need to check if this flag exists for any mediums that are duplicated for each owner.

Comment: could you post some sample data for that and the expected result?

Comment: I have edited my sample data. the result i would expect to see is the same ouput for the query that you posted. I just need to check that if a medium is duplicated, there is 1 "is_std_addr" flag set on the duplicate records.

Comment: I tried that, but if i have 2 records with the same medium it will check that both records have the "is_std_addr" flag. I only need it to be present once

Comment: please post the expected result too

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `Count` Aggregate + `Case` statement

```
select owner_obj_id,
       ddr_medium_id,
       case when count(ddr_medium_id)>1 then 'Duplicate' else 'Unique' END As Dup_Check
from yourable
group by owner_obj_id,ddr_medium_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the owners that have more than one address:

```
select owner_obj_id
from tablename
group by owner_obj_id
having min(addr_medium_id) <> max(addr_medium_id);
```

If you want the original rows, you can use a `join` or do something similar with window functions.  Perhaps the simplest is just `in`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.owner_obj_id in (select owner_obj_id
                         from tablename
                         group by owner_obj_id
                         having min(addr_medium_id) <> max(addr_medium_id)
                        );
```